# How to redirect page to cms page ie.(carrer.html) via controller file?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, forms, redirect-url

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as
possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
return;
```

Comment: You can try this $this->_redirect('/carrer.html'); instead of $this->_redirect('*/*/');

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$url=Mage::getUrl('landing-page'); //page url key

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url); 
exit();
```

Comment: Not working for me.....url convert to "localhost/project/career/index/post/" and give blank response

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'cms-page-Identifier');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as
possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
$this->_redirect('/carrer.html');
return;
```

instead of

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as
possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
return;
```